# Broadcasting and receiving custom UUID with Bluetooth LE on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to write a crossplatform Bluetooth LE - Application using xabre Plugin.BLE (or as an alternative aritchie Plugin.BluetoothLE) on Xamarin.Forms. The app is supposed to detect all bluetooth devices in my surrounding that run my app. Therefore, the app needs to contain two functions:

1) Broadcasting a custom UUID

2) Detect all bluetooth devices near me that broadcast the custom UUID of my Application.

I've searched for hours for a suitable example but haven't found one. Is it possible at all to do it with the given plugin? If not, would it be possible with aritchie's Plugin.BluetoothLE (if so, how would I do it in that case?)
I hope this will help others with the same problem, too, since it seems like there isn't a concrete "how-to" for this problem.